# removeEventListener for "scroll" event in Class

Tags: javascript

In javascript, I have a class that has a `scroll` event that works well. **Multiple `console.log('OK scroll')` displayed.**

```
            const PaginatorInfiniteScroll = class {
                constructor(paginationElement) {
                    ...

                    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
                        this.scroll()
                    })
                }

                scroll()
                {
                    console.log('OK scroll')
                    ...
                }

                endScroll()
                {
                     window.removeEventListener('scroll', () => {
                        console.log('OK remove')
                        this.scroll()
                    }, true)
                }

                ...
```

But when I no longer need this event, I want to delete it.

When I execute `this.endScroll()` I have good `console.log('OK remove')` displayed but I still have the `console.log('OK scroll')` that appears when I scroll.

I think I am performing `removeEventListener('scroll')` badly but don't know how to do it

Comment: You can call `removeEventListener('scroll')` which should remove all attached listeners for that event.  If you want to remove a specific one, then you will need to save off the anonymous method that you are using as a listener, so you can refer to it being the one that needs to be removed, specifically.

Comment: Thank you, but I only want to delete this event. I have other "scroll" events in my page but I don't want to delete them. :)

Comment: Ok, so read the second part of my comment then.

Comment: thanks, how to register an anonymous function? :)

Comment: You are already registering an anonymous function. `addEventListener('scroll', () => {})`.  That arrow function is an anonymous function, as there is no persistent reference to it.  If you want to be able to unregister that method, specifically, you **must** make a reference to it, and then remove that specific event listener later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the callback function in some variable and pass that variable to `removeEventListener` function

```
const callback = () => {
    console.log('OK Scroll');
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', callback);       // add scroll event listener

window.removeEventListener('scroll', callback);    // remove scroll event listener
```

Comment: Thank you, but I only want to delete this event. I have other "scroll" events in my page but I don't want to delete them. :)

Comment: window.removeEventListener('scroll');  gives the error: "TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeEventListener' on 'EventTarget': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present."